# JQuery autocomplete function causing reference error

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using `jquery auto complete` functionality. But occasionally I get ***Reference error:function is undefined*** in `IE` but works in `Chrome`.
This is my code which calls a backend `Java` function.

```
    jQuery('autocomplete').focus(function() {
    var f = jQuery(this);       

        f.autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function(request, response) {
                var etype = jQuery("#type").val();
                Util.getId(
                    function(data) {                        
                        if (!isUserSessionValid(data[0])) {
                            return;
                        }
                        response(exportRespToArray(data));      
                    },
                    etype,
                    f.val(),
                    getLang()
                );              
            }
        });     
});
```

`Util.getId()` is  a backend `java` function that returns data back. On success, the code checks if user session is still valid, if not forward to login screen.
But occasionally  IE displays reference error that `exportRespToArray is undefined`. Both the functions are clearly defined in the external js file which is imported into the jsp. The autocomplete function is initialized through `document.ready` function.

It's legacy code and I am no jQuery expert. I guess the `success` keyword inside the Util.getId() function is optional? Why do I get the reference error `only in IE` if the call was success?

Ok. Did some research and `function(data)` is a `DWR callback` function.I could probably add an `errorHandler` block to find out if any error is returned from server.

```
                  Util.getId(           
                    etype,
                    f.val(),
                    getLang(), {
                        callback:function(data) {                           
                        if (!isUserSessionValid(data[0])) {
                            return;                         }
                        response(exportRespToArray(data));      
                    },
                        errorHandler:function(message) { 
                            alert("Error returned: " + message); 
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Where is defined 'exportRespToArray' function ?

Comment: @Taplar : yes, it calls a server side java function which returns data successfully.

Comment: @MadPapo - 'exportRespToArray' is defined on the same external js file where the autocomplete function  is defined.

Comment: "calls a server side java function" does not mean it "is a java function".  That means it is a javascript function that performs an ajax call.

Comment: Is there any other errors displayed? If there is some other error that happens before the definition of your function it will cause it to not be defined.

Comment: @Taplar - We are using DWR plugin( Direct Web Remoting) -  It allows code in a web browser to use Java functions running on a web server as if those functions were within the browser.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWR_(Java)

Comment: "It allows code in a web browser to use Java functions running on a web server as if those functions were within the browser."  The keywords there being **as if**.  Javascript does not know anything about how to interpret or execute java code.  As that wiki states in the first paragraph, it achieves this by using ajax technology.  The java is *not* in the browser.  The javascript makes ajax calls to make it seem like the java is in the browser, but it is not.

Comment: @Taplar:  Ok, but that function returns data and not the culprit here.

Comment: That's fine.  I'm simply pointing out that you used this description as part of your question, and it's inaccurate, so it's going to lead to confusion.

Comment: The error suggests that `IE` is unable to find or does not see `exportRespToArray()` defined. This can mean it was unable to load the JS file or another error prevented the function from being read and defined. It may be that IE loads the JS file later or after the Ready?